# Differential Equation help: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-3}{x^2 +y^2}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is: solve for $y(x)$

> $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y-3}{x^2 +y^2}$$ 
>   given $y(0)=1$.

I am struggling to find a way to separate the variables.

*Also as a side question*, if you have to integrate $y$ with respect to $dx$.

Would the answer be $\dfrac{y^2}2\dfrac{dx}{dy}$.

My reasoning is that I have integrated y and divided by the derivative of y with respect to x?? I am really unsure...

Note $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: I guess removing the word "urgent" changes the context of the question? That was my rationale for downvoting this question ...

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the inverse function $x(y)$, the equation $\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{x^2 +y^2}{y-3}$ is a Riccati ODE. So, it can be analyticaly solved, but the arduous calculus involves complicated functions ( Kummer and Tricomi functions with complex variables).

Are you sure that there is no mistake in the writting of your equation ?